# Changing the pixel value of the top and bottom 10% of the image to 0 [OpenCV]

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I tried this out with Numpy with the code below but didn't work out. Looking for the fastest way to do this:

```
img[img.shape[0]:int(img.shape[0]*0.1)] = 0
img[int(img.shape[0])*0.9):] = 0
```

`img` is a `np.ndarray`

Comment: What do you mean by *"it didn't work out"* please? Did it crash? Blank the wrong thing? Take 4 days? Please make your code runnable by adding `import` statements and something that creates a minimal, representative image even if just a green rectangle. Thank you.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. All you got to do is create a 2D array with `np.random()`. I see that all across the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Create solid grey image
grey = np.full([100,250], 128, dtype=np.uint8)

# Determine how many rows
N = grey.shape[0]//10

# Make first and last N rows black
grey[:N,  :] = 0
grey[-N:, :] = 0
```

[image]